# Accessibility: Disable VoiceOver / Talkback on password input fields

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, accessibility

Is it possible to disable VoiceOver (iOS) / Talkback (Android) on a password input field without resorting to rolling out a custom keyboard for each platform?

I don't want sensitive information (like password or PIN) spoken out aloud when the user is typing it in.

Comment: On Android it appears to be a user configured setting: https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6283655#zippy=%2Cspeak-passwords

Comment: Simply modify content description in android... What you're providing it'll announce... You can set XML itself

Comment: I can't set the content description on the system keyboard, can i?

Comment: You should not do this as a developer. Password fields are a standard platform component, and you should never mess with the way assistive technology (AT) is exposing these standard components. There are very good reasons for the design decisions, often based on large scale research, and finally users of AT are used to their platform’s behaviour. as Morrison said, it even is a user’s preference setting, and as such you should respect it.

Answer (score 0):

Talkback's voiceover for input text may be disabled for certain TextEdit views by overriding [View.AccessibilityDelegate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.AccessibilityDelegate) with [View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo)) and [View.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.AccessibilityDelegate#onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(android.view.View,%20android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent))

```
    passwordView.setAccessibilityDelegate(new View.AccessibilityDelegate() {
        public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host,                                                          AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
            // 'setPassword(true)' is necessary for disabling voiceover
            //  for whole content of password field with visible content mode
            info.setPassword(true);
        }
        public void onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(View host, AccessibilityEvent event) {
            //do nothing -> no need to perform annotation of editText content changes
        }
    });
```